# Xslt copy element into renamed element

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm struggling to get my Xslt to produce what I'm after.

I have the following xml

```
<data>
    <things>
        <name>A</name>
    </things>
    <other>
        <type>B</type>
    </other>
</data>
```

and I want my output xml to be

```
<data>
    <stuff>
        <name>A</name>
        <type>B</type>
    </stuff>    
</data>
```

I have the following xslt so far but this doesn't produce exactly what I'm after

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data/things">
    <xsl:element name="stuff">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data/other">
    <xsl:element name="stuff">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is probably very simple so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is probably very simple

Well, it could be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <stuff>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*"/>
        </stuff>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or, if you want to be explicit, make the second template:

```
<xsl:template match="/data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <stuff>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="things/name | other/type"/>
        </stuff>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with the second template. As @cis correctly pointed out my mockup was simple but my real requirement is a lot more complicated so being explicit was definitely needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your mockup is maybe a little bit **too** simple, but I'd suggest something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <stuff>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </stuff>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name|type">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically, the template for "data" puts its own tag in, wrapps all its content in "stuff". The templates for "name" and "type" simply copy the current context node. And that's it.

Comment: Your first template is redundant.